# Duplicate tab with windows

Tags: split, tabbed-user-interface

I have opened several files in vim (particularly, in vimdiff). They are opened in multiple (vertically split) windows.

Is there a simple way, in which I can duplicate all this to another tab?

I could write a function, which will open a new tab & loop through all buffers in current tab to open in new tab using split/diffsplit. But I wanted to know, if there is an easier way.

Comment: As far as I can tell that's pretty much the only way.

Comment: OK... I will try to write one such script...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:mksession` with a specialized `'sessionoptions'` to make this easier.

```
:set sessionoptions=blank,help,folds,winsize,localoptions
:mksession
:tabnew
:source Session.vim
```

Using this technique we can create an easy to use command. Put the following command in your `vimrc`:

```
command! -bar DuplicateTabpane
      \ let s:sessionoptions = &sessionoptions |
      \ try |
      \   let &sessionoptions = 'blank,help,folds,winsize,localoptions' |
      \   let s:file = tempname() |
      \   execute 'mksession ' . s:file |
      \   tabnew |
      \   execute 'source ' . s:file |
      \ finally |
      \   silent call delete(s:file) |
      \   let &sessionoptions = s:sessionoptions |
      \   unlet! s:file s:sessionoptions |
      \ endtry
```

Now you can just call `:DuplicateTabpane`.

For more information see:

```
:h :mksession
:h :mkview
:h 'sessionoptions'
:h :tabnew
:h :source
```

Comment: Good enough... Plus, it will most likely maintain window positions for horizontally split windows too. I will accept this answer, after some more testing... Thanks

Comment: Works great. I also added the &diff logic from my answer to this answer in my `.exrc`..

Comment: Diff should work when `'sessionoptions'` has the `localoptions` value.

Answer (score 2):

Wrote this function. Worked for me.

Note: This will only work for windows split vertically. This was sufficient for me. :-)

```
set splitright
function! DuplicateTab()
    "Note current position & view settings.
    let cur_win=winnr() - 1
    let view=winsaveview()
    "Are we running under vimdiff?
    let use_diff=&diff
    "Open new tab
    tabnew
    "Go to previous tab
    tabprev
    " For every window, open window in next tab
    windo exec "let localview=winsaveview() | let x=bufnr(\"\")|tabnext|vnew|exec 'buf ' . x | call winrestview(localview) | tabprev"

    " Reset first tab's position.
    exec winnr(). "wincmd h"
    exec cur_win . "wincmd l"
    call winrestview(view)

    "Go to next tab & close first (empty) window
    tabnext
    exec winnr() . "wincmd h"
    q
    "Go to the same window being used in current (previous) tab
    exec cur_win . "wincmd l"

    " If running under vimdiff, start diff view
    if(use_diff)
        windo diffthis
    endif
endfunction
```